# Unhandled promise rejection warning with Mocha, Chai and Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm using `Node` and have the following `ES6` class:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const sqlFileReader = require('../database/SqlFileReader');
const Lnfe = require('../errors/LoanNotFoundError');

const epoch = '1970-01-01';

/**
 * Take the input params and return the clientId (either found via loanId or untouched) and dateString we need
*/
class ParameterParser {

static async prepareInputParameters(con, req) {

    let clientId = req.query.client_id; // Will be overriden if we need and are able to obtain the client id via loan id.
    let dateString;

    // If no client_id is given but loan_id is, get the client_id via loan_id:
    if (typeof req.query.client_id === 'undefined' && typeof req.query.loan_id !== 'undefined') {
        const { retData } = await sqlFileReader.read('./src/database/sql/getClientIdFromLoanId.sql', [`${req.query.loan_id}`], con, req.logger);
        if (retData.rowsCount > 0) {
            clientId = retData.rows[0].client_id;
        }
        else {
            throw new Lnfe(400, req);
        }
    }

    if (typeof req.query.complaint_init_date === 'undefined') {
        dateString = epoch;
    }
    else {
        // Need to subtract 6 years from the complaint_init_date:
        dateString = moment(moment(req.query.complaint_init_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()).subtract(6, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }

    return { clientId, dateString };
}

}

module.exports = ParameterParser;
```

I am testing it using `Mocha`, `Chai`, `Chai-as-Promised` and `Sinon`:

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const parameterParser = require('../../src/core/ParameterParser.js');
const sqlFileReader = require('../../src/database/SqlFileReader.js');
const Lnfe = require('../../src/errors/LoanNotFoundError');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

const retData = {
rowsCount: 1,
rows: [{ client_id: 872 }],
};

const reqDateAndLoan = {
query: {
    complaint_init_date: '2022-03-15',
    loan_id: '1773266',
},
};

const reqDateAndClient = {
query: {
    complaint_init_date: '2022-03-15',
    client_id: '872',
},
};

const reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist = {
query: {
    complaint_init_date: '2022-03-15',
    loan_id: '1773266999999999999',
},
};

describe('prepareInputParameters', () => {

sinon.stub(sqlFileReader, 'read').returns({ retData });

it('results in correct client id and date string', async () => {
    const ret = { clientId: 872, dateString: '2016-03-15' };
    expect(await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoan)).to.deep.equal(ret);
});

it('results in a client id equal to the that input if the request query contains a client id', async () => {
    const ret = { clientId: '872', dateString: '2016-03-15' };
    expect(await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndClient)).to.deep.equal(ret);
});

it('throws a \'Loan Not Found\' error', async () => {
    expect(parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist)).eventually.throw(Lnfe, 400, 'Loan Not Found');
});

it('DOES NOT throw a \'Loan Not Found\' error', async () => {
    expect(async () => {
        await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist);
    }).to.not.throw(Lnfe, 400, 'Loan Not Found');
});


});
```

The tests pass but the output has an couple of node warnings:

```
prepareInputParameters
✓ results in correct client id and date string
✓ results in a client id equal to the that input if the request query contains a client id
✓ throws a 'Loan Not Found' error
(node:23875) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: Loan Not Found: expected { Object (clientId, dateString) } to be a function
(node:23875) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
✓ DOES NOT throw a 'Loan Not Found' error


4 passing (19ms)
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of these warnings or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the function `catch` for every promise execution.  For example: `await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoan).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: @Ele changing my code to `expect(parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist)).catch(err => console.log(err)).eventually.throw(Lnfe, 400, 'Loan Not Found');` results in the error: `Error: Invalid Chai property: catch. Did you mean "match"?`

Comment: you are adding `catch` to the wrong function object

Comment: @0.sh has explained it `:)`

Comment: So what should that line of code be instead of `expect(parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist)).eventually.throw(Lnfe, 400, 'Loan Not Found');` please?

Comment: Use this in the executor function 
new Promise(() => { throw new Error('exception!'); });
and use .catch in the call to await parameterparsed method call -         await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(null, reqDateAndLoanIdThatDoesNotExist).catch(error => { console.log('caught', error.message); }) and log here the result.

Comment: Check my answer for usage of catch and await to wait for the promise rejection

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas to help you understand the different stages of the promise that I compiled (the example, ie) with a ES6 class:

// asyncpromiserejection.js

```
class asyncpromise{ 
    constructor(s){
        this.s=s
    }
PTest(){    
    var somevar = false;
    somevar=this.s;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (somevar === true)
            resolve();
 //       else
   //         reject();
    });
}
}
module.exports=asyncpromise
```

With the else part commented, the promise would either resolve if true is passed to the class or the test would timeout because the promise does not know what to do when the value is false.

// test.js

```
const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
describe("asyncTests", () => {
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    var t=new asyncpromise(false)
    await t.PTest().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
})
})        
});
```

**Fig 1.0**
[image: Fig 1.0]

Uncomment the else part and you will get the same error but with the warning that promise rejection has been deprecated - Fig 1.1 - because now, although the promise rejection due to the falsey value is handled in the code, the test ie., the calling method, has not handled it.

```
class asyncpromise{ 
    constructor(s){
        this.s=s
    }
PTest(){    
    var somevar = false;
    somevar=this.s;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (somevar === true)
            resolve();
        else
            reject();
    });
}
}
module.exports=asyncpromise
```

**Fig 1.1**
[image: Fig 1.1]

Now, handle the promise rejection in the test like so:

```
const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
describe("asyncTests", () => {
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    var t=new asyncpromise(false)
    await t.PTest().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
}).catch(()=>{console.log("Promise rejcted")})
})        
});
```

[image]

And, you can pass some custom message in the reject part of the promise to assert in a test like so:

```
const assert=require('chai').assert
const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
describe("asyncTests", () => {
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    var t=new asyncpromise(false)
    await t.PTest().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Promise rejected")
    assert.equal(error.message,"Promise rejected")
})
})        
});
```

// asyncpromiserejection.js

```
class asyncpromise{ 
    constructor(s){
        this.s=s
    }
PTest(){    
    var somevar = false;
    somevar=this.s;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (somevar === true)
            resolve();
        else
           throw new Error("Promise rejcted")
            //reject();
    });
}
}
module.exports=asyncpromise
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use to catch unhandled rejection using

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, p) => {
  console.error('unhandledRejection', err.stack, p)
})
```

so I have the trace and I can locate and fix

for `DeprecationWarning` should work this - I'm not sure, but accordingly with documentation https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_warning

```
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
  console.warn(warning.name);
  console.warn(warning.message);
  console.warn(warning.stack);
});
```

Comment: I wonder, what is the best place to put such code? You would not add it to every code file with tests, would you?

Comment: mocha global setup hook, check out http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2015/04/node-mocha-hooks-set-up-and-tear-down.html

Comment: Cool! Looks like `before()` root-level hook is a way to go https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks